# context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand - Error code 701 - Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure

I have the following code in the migration configuration seeding method:

```
string sqlQuery = // 22 mb file contents
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( sqlQuery );
```

The `ExecuteSqlCommand` function is making Azure throw this error:

> The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please
>   try again. Error code 701. A severe error occurred on the current
>   command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Why might this be? I really can't find much information on it

Comment: Thanks man, I have divided my sql command into 9 seperate batches, seems to have solved the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL error 701 according to my googling is the following:

> SQL Server has failed to allocate sufficient memory to run the query.
>   This can be caused by a variety of reasons including operating system
>   settings, physical memory availability, or memory limits on the
>   current workload. In most cases, the transaction that failed is not
>   the cause of this error.

May be time for an upgrade, or change what your query is pulling back or splitting it out into separate queries.